# Returning multiple values from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm a newcomer to JavaScript and I'm sure this is very straightforward: I wish to set a number of values based upon a single input in a switch statement.  I know in Java I would use getters/setters and or pass the values into an array and pick the relevant field based on its index.

```js
let custCode;
let loyaltyCode;
let id;

const setCustomerCodes = () => {
  switch (customerType) {
    case "NEW":
      (custCode = "19202"), (loyaltyCode = "X78"), (id = "396550");
      break;
    case "CURRENT":
      (custCode = "93893"), (loyaltyCode = "X89"), (id = "396438"); 
      break;
    case "LOYAL":
      (custCode = "76353"), (loyaltyCode = "X90"), (id = "396440"); 
      break;
    default:
      (custCode = "02902"), (loyaltyCode = "X80"), (id = "396637"); 
      break;
  }
  return //all values as an object?;
};

module.exports = {
   //export the values to use in separate file 
};
```

I then just want to use the value of each field in a separate JS file. I know this is very basic; easier when I can get my head around debugging in VS Code

Comment: "*return //all values as an object?*" -> `return { custCode, loyaltyCode, id }`

Comment: Is this for nodeJS?

Comment: @Rehan yes, nodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```js
let custCode;
let loyaltyCode;
let id;

const setCustomerCodes = (customerType) => {
  switch (customerType) {
    case "NEW":
      (custCode = "19202"), (loyaltyCode = "X78"), (id = "396550");
      break;
    case "CURRENT":
      (custCode = "93893"), (loyaltyCode = "X89"), (id = "396438"); 
      break;
    case "LOYAL":
      (custCode = "76353"), (loyaltyCode = "X90"), (id = "396440"); 
      break;
    default:
      (custCode = "02902"), (loyaltyCode = "X80"), (id = "396637"); 
      break;
  }
  return {custCode, loyaltyCode, id}
};

let x = setCustomerCodes("NEW");
console.log(x);
console.log(x.custCode);
console.log(x.loyaltyCode);
console.log(x.id);
```

As @VLAZ suggests, you simply return all of the values in {} as a single object.  The `x` variable I have defined can then be used to get to the individual values (as shown in the separate `console.log(...)` entries.

Note that you do need to pass in a value for `customerType`, so I've included that as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I think you could return an object.

```js
const setCustomerCodes = () => {
  switch (customerType) {
    case "NEW":
      return {custCode: "19202", loyaltyCode: "X78", id: "396550"}
    case "CURRENT":
      return {custCode: "93893", loyaltyCode: "X89", id: "396438"}; 
    case "LOYAL":
      return {custCode: "76353", loyaltyCode: "X90", id: "396440"}; 
    default:
      return {custCode: "02902", loyaltyCode: "X80", id: "396637"}; 
  }
};
const {
  custCode,
  loyaltyCode,
  id,
  } = setCustomerCodes()
module.exports = {
  custCode,
  loyaltyCode,
  id,
};
```